# Seleccionar valores dentro de una tabla por filas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

¿Cómo puedo seleccionar valores de una tabla de html por filas en JavaScript?, tengo la siguiente función ya hecha pero eso me junta todas las filas

```
    function iiid(e) {
    var iii = "";
    $("td").parent("tr").find("td").each(function () {
        iii += $(this).html() + ",";
    });
    return iii;
}
```

Comment: Qué es exactamente lo que necesitas? No termino de entender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En lugar de seleccionar todas las celdas y hacer un bucle sobre ellas, puedes hacer dos bucles(`each`) anidados: uno para las filas y otro para las celdas de la fila:

```js
function iiid(e) {
  var result = [];
  $('tr').each(function(){
    var fila = [];
    $(this).find('td').each(function(){
      fila.push($(this).html());
    });
    result.push(fila.join());
  });
  return result;
}

$(function(){
  $('#leerFilas').click(function(){
    var data = iiid();
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>1.1</td>
  <td>1.2</td>
  <td>1.3</td>
  <td>1.4</td>
  <td>1.5</td>
  <td>1.6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2.1</td>
  <td>2.2</td>
  <td>2.3</td>
  <td>2.4</td>
  <td>2.5</td>
  <td>2.6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>3.1</td>
  <td>3.2</td>
  <td>3.3</td>
  <td>3.4</td>
  <td>3.5</td>
  <td>3.6</td>
</tr>
</table>
<button id="leerFilas">Leer filas</button>
```

Comment: Gracias, sí me sirvió.

Answer (score 0):

Con esta función sumas los valores de cada columna por filas de tu tabla

```
function sumaColumnasTabla(){
    var total = 0;
    $("#idDetuTabla").find("tr").each(function(){
         $(this).find("td").each(function(){
                total+=parseFloat($(this).text());
        });
    });
    return total;
}
```